# Error en PHP al iniciar sesion

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli, login

Buenos Dias,

Estoy Haciendo un login y he estado investigando y mejorandolo ya que el anterior que tenia no era muy eficaz que digamos.

Codigo:

```
    <?php

//Conectamos a la base de datos
require('/conexion.php');

//Obtenemos los datos del formulario de acceso
$userPOST = $_POST["userAcceso"]; 
$passPOST = $_POST["passAcceso"];

//Filtro anti-XSS
$userPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $userPOST));
$passPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $passPOST));

//Definimos la cantidad máxima de caracteres
//Esta comprobación se tiene en cuenta por si se llegase a modificar el "maxlength" del formulario
//Los valores deben coincidir con el tamaño máximo de la fila de la base de datos
$maxCaracteresUser0 = "20";
$maxCaracteresPassword0 = "60";

//Si los input son de mayor tamaño, se "muere" el resto del código y muestra la respuesta correspondiente
if(strlen($userPOST) > $maxCaracteresUser0) {
    die('El nombre de usuario no puede superar los '.$maxCaracteresUser0.' caracteres');
};

if(strlen($passPOST) > $maxCaracteresPassword0) {
    die('La contraseña no puede superar los '.$maxCaracteresPassword0.' caracteres');
};

//Pasamos el input del usuario a minúsculas para compararlo después con
//el campo "usernamelowercase" de la base de datos
$userPOSTMinusculas = strtolower($userPOST);

//Escribimos la consulta necesaria
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `usuario0` WHERE User0='".$userPOSTMinusculas."'";

//Obtenemos los resultados
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

//Guardamos los resultados del nombre de usuario en minúsculas
//y de la contraseña de la base de datos
$userBD = $datos['User0'];
$passwordBD = $datos['Password0'];

//Comprobamos si los datos son correctos
if($userBD == $userPOSTMinusculas and password_verify($passPOST, $passwordBD)){

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos['User0'];
    $_SESSION['estado'] = 'Autenticado';

    /* Sesión iniciada, si se desea, se puede redireccionar desde el servidor */

//Si los datos no son correctos, o están vacíos, muestra un error
//Además, hay un script que vacía los campos con la clase "acceso" (formulario)
} else if ( $userBD != $userPOSTMinusculas || $userPOST == "" || $passPOST == "" || !password_verify($passPOST, $passwordBD) ) {
    die ('<script>$(".acceso").val("");</script>
Los datos de acceso son incorrectos');
} else {
    die('Error');
};
?>
```

y me sale este error o advertencia, pero aun asi no loguea y la conexion a la base de datos es correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las lineas mencionada en la imagen anterior:

```
11 $userPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $userPOST));

12 $passPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $passPOST));


37 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

38 $datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

Este es el codigo de conexion.php:

```
    <?php
// Conexión a la base de datos 
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678','web_juegos'); 

// Si la conexión falla, aparece el error 
if($connection === false) { 
 echo 'Ha habido un error <br>'.mysqli_connect_error(); 
} else {
 echo 'Conectado a la base de datos';
}
?>
```

Creo que no me funciona porque no le estoy mandando nada.... o eso creo

Comment: El error dice que `$conexion` es _null_. ¿Puedes comprobar si `require('/conexion.php');` devuelve esa variable y se trata de una conexión válida?

Comment: si esta en la misma carpeta no es necesario de esa forma debe ser require('conexion.php');

Comment: esta en la misma carpeta

Comment: sigue igual :(  men

Comment: puedes corroborar la variable `$conexion` y mostrar por pantalla lo que te devuelve?

Comment: editare la pregunta

Comment: agregue el codigo de conexion, creo que es porque no le estoy mandando nada... o eso es lo que creo

Comment: cambia el requiere por include

Comment: tampoco es ese ya lo cambie y sigue igual

Comment: vamos al chat esto ya se esta alargando mucho porfavor http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: En lugar de usar sentencias dinámicas, sería mejor usar sentencias preparadas/parametrizadas. MySQLi las soporta, son más seguras y te ahorrarías estos problemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en el conexion.php tienes :

```
**$connection** = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678','web_juegos');
```

en el access tienes

```
$userPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string(**$conexion**, $userPOST));
```

te recomiento esto en el conexion.php:

```
function conectarBD(){
// Conexión a la base de datos 

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678','web_juegos'); 

    // Si la conexión falla, aparece el error 
    if($connection === false) { 
     echo 'Ha habido un error <br>'.mysqli_connect_error(); 
    } else {
     echo 'Conectado a la base de datos';
    }
    return $connection;
    }
```

en el access algo asi:

```
include('conexion.php');
$conexion = conectarBD();
```

y tus demas acciones con base de datos deben ser con el mismo nombre

```
11 $userPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion , $userPOST));

12 $passPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion , $passPOST));

37 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion , $consulta);

38 $datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

Comment: Donde va esto: `$conexion = conectarBD();
`

Comment: al inicio de cada archivo que necesites conexion a base de datos

Comment: por cierto los * no van lo coloque para que vieras donde es el error

Comment: tranquilo ya se XD